# Inequality with indicators

Tags: inequality

I recently stuck on proving this inequality. If you re interested in and have some ideas about this inequality please share with me, I really appreciate. Have a nice day.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y57kT.png)

For $a_1 ,...,a_n$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $( a_1+...+a_n)^2 1_{ | a_1+...+a_n | \leq 1 }  \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} 2^{ n-i}1_{ |  a_1+...+a_i |  >  1 }  + \sum_{i=1}^{n} 2^{ n+1-i}a_i^2 1_{|  a_i  |    \leq 2 }$.